# PyQt4 webkit - google maps markers are not loading

Tags: javascript, python, pyqt, google-maps-markers, qwebview

I have a simple example that loads a google map in a QWebView.
Here's the Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import os
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
tempPath = "file:///" + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "simple.html").replace('\\','/')
print tempPath
web.load(QUrl(tempPath))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here's the code inside `*simple.html*`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the markers does not load inside the `QWebView`, as you can see they load just fine in the browser.
PS. this issue is on windows, it does not occur on linux.
[image: Screenshot when I run the example on windows]

Any idea how to solve this ?

---

UPDATE : 
After debugging, I get this error in the javascript console

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.G.bind(this)') in marker.js:51
```

Comment: I recommend running it in a cmd and attach the messages you see. I also recommend that you enable the debug mode of QWebView to see if it generates any error in the load of any package. Also I recommend you disable firewalls.

Comment: To debug use the following: `web.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)`,  Then right click and select Inspect, then go to console and observe the messages. It would also be useful if you go to the network tab.

Comment: eyllanesc
I did as you recommended and I got this error 
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.G.bind(this)')
in marker.js line 51

Comment: This implies that you have not correctly accessed "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false", check your firewall.

Comment: I disabled the firewall, and I still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Also late to the party, but I was having the exact same issue but with `wkhtmltopdf` (also uses`QTWeb`). The **this.G.bind** error happens because `QTWeb` does not support **'bind'**.

This must've been introduced when Google Maps forced an upgrade recently, and retired the version I was previously using 3.29 I think. Anyways, if you add this polyfill to the top of the page, it should fix your issue

```
<script>
  // PhantomJS/QTWeb does not support bind
  Function.prototype.bind = Function.prototype.bind || function(thisp) {
    var fn = this;
    return function() {
      return fn.apply(thisp, arguments);
    };
  };
</script>
```

Comment: I had the similar issue as author and your solution really fixed the problem! Thanks) PS. I've started porting my app to python3 with PyQt5 to use QWebEngine which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if Im late to the party. I did find a tweek in the mechanism of how google maps operate where you can get static map jpg upon etering api defined url code where you can adjust co ordinates if you want.

Note: This can be used only if its static map like displaying and no further action

I have just tweeked your code such that it displays the Image with marker on the map:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import os
import urllib
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
coordinates="13.0329,77.6136"
web.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
coadder="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?   center="+coordinates+"&zoom=16&markers=color:red%7Clabel:D%7C"+coordinates+"&size=1500x400"
urllib.urlretrieve(coadder, "local-filename.jpg")
tempPath = "file:///" + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "local-filename.jpg").replace('\\','/')
print tempPath
web.load(QUrl(tempPath))
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> as you can see https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?   center=13.0329,77.6136&zoom=16&markers=color:red%7Clabel:D%7C13.0329,77.6136&size=1500x400

This url is from google maps api for more info

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro

If you're intending for adding multiple pins on the map just add

> markers=color:red%7Clabel:D%7C13.0329,77.6136

just go through the above link for details.

Although this is extremely crude way of doing it but with respect to PyQt4 QwebView I did read lot of speculation on readability of javascripts on that webview(for marking the location).I could only figure this out as an alternative.
Hope this helps.
Peace.